# WebBrowser Control Retrieving jQuery Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to retrieve whenever the website displays the following message from a jQuery event. Initially this HTML inst displayed in the HTML.

```
 <div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right"><div class="toast toast-error" aria-live="assertive" style="display: block;"><div class="toast-message">Check email &amp; password.</div></div></div>
```

My assumption is, that the **webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains** is only looking from the initial load of the content.

So I thought maybe some sort of timer would work every 5 seconds, looking to see if the code has changed - but I don't even think this is right as it's checking the code that's already loaded repeatedly?

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Checks for any errors on sign in page

            if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("toast toast-error"))
            {
                // Toast Notifications
                var signinErrorNotification = new Notification("Error", "Please check your email and password are correct.", 50, FormAnimator.AnimationMethod.Fade, FormAnimator.AnimationDirection.Left);
                signinErrorNotification.Show();
            }

    }
```

How do I go about getting the latest code that's been affected by any jQuery.

P.S. My c# level is beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Document property should give you what you need.

Notice that the docs for DocumentText say

> Gets or sets the HTML contents of the page displayed in the WebBrowser
>   control.

For Document they say

> Gets an HtmlDocument representing the Web page currently displayed in the WebBrowser control.

To me that's saying that DocumentText is like the starting document and Document is the current DOM.  Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-access-the-managed-html-document-object-model